# Music's disappeared

Tags: itunes, windows

Today I turned my computer on and I afterwards opened iTunes.
To my surprise, my music disappeared, everything that I had was gone.
I have no idea what happened and I have no idea how to put it back the way it was.

I had everything organized, I spent hours on end to put everything together when I switched computers and now everything's gone again. I can't sync my phone anymore as long as this stays like it is.

Has anyone got any idea how I can put it back? Is there a backup I don't know of that I can use? I don't remember doing any backup.

Comment: Are you using an external drive for your music? Did it get disconnected?
Did you accidentally open a different iTunes library?
Is the music still in the folder where you stored it?

Comment: No, I dind't disconnect anything, not that I know of. The music files are still in the same place, yes. But every single change that I've made in terms of organisation, went way.

Comment: Who else has access to your account ?

Comment: Is all the music still in Music -> iTunes -> iTunes Media -> Music? Is there an "iTunes Music Library.xml" in the iTunes folder? Feel free to edit your question with answers to some of these queries.